# 'str' object has no attribute 'pop'

Tags: python

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'pop'

```
a = input('enter a list : ')
p = 2
i = 0
l = len(a)
while l>0:
    i = (p+i)%l
    print(a.pop(i))
    l -= 1
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: its showing 'str' object has no attribute 'pop' error .... so how can i solve it

Comment: you must explain what you are trying to do, what is the expected behaviour...

Comment: `input()`returns a string (unless you're using Python 2 where it returns a security hole).

Comment: question is : Write a Python program to remove and print every third number from a list of numbers until the list becomes empty.

Comment: if u will take a = [1,2,3,4,5] directly instead of a = input() it ll give u the answer bt i want it with input

Comment: @smrutiranjan But there is no third number when the list has less than three items. Do you want to remove and print the last item instead in that case?

Comment: could you please edit your question to make clear what you are exactly asking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a` is assigned a string returned by `input()`, so you need to turn it into a list first before you can use list methods such as `pop()` on it.

For example, by using `a.split()` you can treat `a` as a space-delimited string:

```
a = input('enter a list : ')
n = a.split()
p = 2
i = 0
l = len(n)
while l>0:
    i = (p+i)%l
    print(n.pop(i))
    l -= 1
```

Sample input and output:

```
enter a list : 3 5 2 1
2
5
1
3
```